# How to embed a ViewPager and a LinearLayout in a Linearlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

The inner LinearLayout is gone although I have set its `layout_height` to be '100dp'.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/page_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/seek_bar"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/toggle"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: I want the orientation of inner layout to be horizontal. So I set its `layout_height` to be `wrap_content`. Now, it is almost done. However, something is wrong with SeekBar, the thumbnail is not central at the vertical bar. 
[image]

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/page_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toggle"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `weight` instead. I've modified the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/page_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <!-- app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/toggle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Since `layout_weight` specify a size **ratio between multiple views**, U need to specify the size `0dp` so that view can be measured correctly.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. There is something wrong with the thumbnail, counld you please help me?  ( Description is in the updated question.)